# Convert locale date string to timestamp. Java / Android

Tags: java, android, date, time, timestamp

Currently I’m using the following code to create a datetime string based on the users’ locale.

```
Calendar todayC = Calendar.getInstance() ;
Date today = todayC.getTime();
return today.toLocaleString();
```

This will return a string in the following format (different for each locale):

- US: (en_US)  returns:  **Feb 26, 2014 10:27:53 PM**
- Germany (de_DE) returns: **26.02.2014 22:28:57**
- France (fr_FR) returns: **26 fèvr. 2014 22:30:27**
- Norway(Nb_NO) returns: **26. Feb. 2014 22:25:54**
  … and so on

I have saved these strings in a database, and now need to sort the database by date.
Sorting based on these stings is probably not easy, so my question is:

**How can I convert these strings to a timestamp?**

Comment: What format are you wanting to get the timestamps in?

Comment: I'd advise never to store "user-friendly" locale-specific date strings in a database. Use either the long value or a big-endian form as used by ISO8601 as shown in the two examples in the answer from Dayan Gonzalez.

Comment: Drewness: i think unix timestamp would be a good choice.

Comment: Squonk: Yes i agree. Learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your date value in a `long` value that is more simple to sort:

```
Calendar todayC = Calendar.getInstance() ;
Date today = todayC.getTime();
long longValue = today.getTime();
return longValue;
```

You can return directly the `long` value, or you can convert the date value with specific format returning a `String` value:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar todayC = Calendar.getInstance() ;
Date today = todayC.getTime();
String stringValue = sdf.format(today);
return stringValue;
```

I hope it is useful.

Comment: This is helpful, but i need to convert the strings that are already saved in the database. As you can see in my first post these strings are different for each locale. Since the strings don't have one specific format eg("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") i can't find how to parse them back to a date object.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing the `long` values (millisecond since epoch) of your dates in the database, and sort by those. When you actually need to display the date value to the user, then create a date object with the long value and format it the way you want to. A database is design to store data, not labels.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, I might keep the timestamp as a Date in your database and use the locale when you want to display it.
It will be more consistent and the dates will be easier to work with.